# SQL Procedure and Reporting table Creation based upon numerous Monthly views

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I have numerous monthly tables in Azure SQL for example dbo.Fresh_202001,dbo.Fresh_202002,dbo.Fresh_202003 etc used for history staging tables.

I would like to know from a design point of view, what would be the best way to either build a procedure where i would like the output to generate a reporting table with only the latest month's worth of data, meaning the procedure or reporting view should always on month end only read from the latest month history table data.

For example we have upcoming month end and the reporting view should read this month's data ie dbo.Fresh_202006

Would one make use of a variable for the month you want to report on, union all the tables and only bring back the CURRENT_DATE etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For a design POV, you shouldn't have monthly tables. At least not without a good reason. And "best way" is a very subjective (non-existent really) measure. You mention these are "staging" tables, so why would this be related to "reporting". You also refer to "reporting view" and "stored procedure". I suggest you take a step back and have a broad discussion with your team members about requirements, design, direction, and proper usage. Seems you might be missing proper focus in your system design.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a view once per month as part of the process that creates the data.  The last step would be:

```
alter view v_current_fresh
    select *
    from <the just-created-data>;
```

Note that such a view really requires dynamic SQL; the above is the idea.

This could also be scheduled as a trigger on a `create table` in the database.  Or as a job on its own schedule.

Comment: That can work for sure yes,Thank you, Any suggestions in using the dynamic sql i can for example add FROM ' + @table  and make sure the view as mentioned always selects from the latest or just created data, how can one go about this?

Comment: Maybe using a synonyn for the "current data" table and just changing the synonym on the first day of every month?

Comment: Thanks SMor that also sounds easy enough, how can i go about implementing that?

Answer (score 0):

To Follow up with Team as our requirements for the solution needs to be discussed.